# How to exclude predictions previously seen movies. Tensorflow Recommenders (TFRS)

Tags: tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I use the Tensorflow Recommender (TFRS) and get recommendations for previously watched movies
https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval

The manual says:

...The model is re-recommending some of users' already watched movies. These known-positive watches can crowd out test movies out of top K recommendations...
..can be tackled by excluding previously seen movies from test recommendations.

How can I exclude previously watched movies from test recommendations?
At what stage should this be done?